# Kafka 0.9-Java : consumer skipping offsets during application restart

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a java application with below properties

```
kafkaProperties = new Properties();
kafkaProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaBrokersList);
kafkaProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, consumerGroupName);
kafkaProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
kafkaProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
kafkaProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, consumerSessionTimeoutMs);
kafkaProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_PARTITION_FETCH_BYTES_CONFIG, maxPartitionFetchBytes);
kafkaProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
```

**I've created 15 consumer threads and let them process the below runnable .I don't have any other consumer with this consumer group name consuming .**

```
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        logger.info("Starting ConsumerWorker, consumerId={}", consumerId);
        consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList(kafkaTopic), offsetLoggingCallback);
        while (true) {
            boolean isPollFirstRecord = true;
            logger.debug("consumerId={}; about to call consumer.poll() ...", consumerId);
            ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(pollIntervalMs);
            Map<Integer,Long> partitionOffsetMap = new HashMap<>();
            for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {

                if (isPollFirstRecord) {
                    isPollFirstRecord = false;
                    logger.info("Start offset for partition {} in this poll : {}", record.partition(), record.offset());
                }
                messageProcessor.processMessage(record.value(), record.offset());
                partitionOffsetMap.put(record.partition(),record.offset());
            }
            if (!records.isEmpty()) {
                logger.info("Invoking commit for partition/offset : {}", partitionOffsetMap);
                consumer.commitAsync(offsetLoggingCallback);
            }
        }
    } catch (WakeupException e) {
        logger.warn("ConsumerWorker [consumerId={}] got WakeupException - exiting ... Exception: {}",
                consumerId, e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("ConsumerWorker [consumerId={}] got Exception - exiting ... Exception: {}",
                consumerId, e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        logger.warn("ConsumerWorker [consumerId={}] is shutting down ...", consumerId);
        consumer.close();
    }
}
```

I also have a OffsetCommitCallbackImpl like below . It basically maintains the partition's and their commited offset as map .It also logs whenever offset is committed .

```
@Override
    public void onComplete(Map<TopicPartition, OffsetAndMetadata> offsets, Exception exception) {
        if (exception == null) {
            offsets.forEach((topicPartition, offsetAndMetadata) -> {
                partitionOffsetMap.put(topicPartition, offsetAndMetadata);
                logger.info("Offset position during the commit for consumerId : {}, partition : {}, offset : {}", Thread.currentThread().getName(), topicPartition.partition(), offsetAndMetadata.offset());
            });
        } else {
            offsets.forEach((topicPartition, offsetAndMetadata) -> logger.error("Offset commit error, and partition offset info : {}, partition : {}, offset : {}", exception.getMessage(), topicPartition.partition(), offsetAndMetadata.offset()));
        }
    }
```

**Problem/Issue :**
   I noticed that i miss events/messages whenever i (restart) bring the application down and bring it back up . So when i closely looked at the logging . by comparing the offsets that are committed(**using offsetcommitcallback logging**) before shutdown vs offsets that are picked up for processing after restart, i see that for certain partition we did not pickup the offset where we left before shutdown. sometimes the start offset for certain partition's are like 1000 more than the committed offset .

**NOTE : This happens to like 8 out of 40 partitions**

If you closely look at the logging in run method there is one log statement where i actually print the offset before invoking async commit . For example if that last log before shutdown shows that as 10 for partition 1 . After restart the first offset we are processing for partition 1 would be like 100 . And i validated that we are exactly missing 90 messages .

Can any one think of a reason why this would be happening ?

Comment: How many Consumers you have with the same group name ?

Comment: Just this one . There are no other consumers other than this application .

Comment: If you are using High Level Consumer you actually don't need to use commitAsync() method. HighLevelConsumer automatically handles all commits unless you set auto-commit to false.

Comment: @misterbaykal As you can see in my properties, i've intentionally set autocommit to false .

Comment: @Dhyan is it really necessary?

Comment: Of course .That is my use-case . I cannot commit offset unless i processMyMessage .

Comment: Can you reproduce with commit sync or using commit sync just before closing?